# Writing JSON File with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im trying to develop a little warn system for my Discord Bot. If someone types !warn @mention Reason, it should store the data in a JSON File. It works, but only with one User in one Guild. What I want is, that
the JSON File looks like this:

```
     {
        "superniceguildid": 
          {
            "member": "636302212787601408",
            "warns": 3
        },
         {
            "meber": "7837439745387549"
            "warns": 1
       }
}
```

Now only this exists:

```
{
    "627818561947041816": {
        "guild": "636302212787601408",
        "warns": 3
    },
   
}
```

How can I do it, that the File is generating like above?
My current code is this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'warn',
    description: "test",
    execute(message, args){
        const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
        const client = new Client()

        const fs = require("fs")
        const ms = require("ms")
        warns = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./warns.json", "utf8"))
        client.servers = require ("./servers.json")
        let guild = client.servers[message.guild.id].message
        
        
/*Embeds*/
const oops = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Error")
        .setColor("RED")
        .setDescription("You cant warn a member. Please ask a Moderator")
        .setAuthor("MemeBot", "this is a link")

const Mod = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Error")
        .setColor("RED")
        .setDescription("You cant warn a Moderator.")
        .setAuthor("MemeBot", "linkhere xD")
/**Commands */
let wUser = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.fetch(`${args[0]}`)
if (!wUser) return message.channel.send("Are you sure, that this was a User? I think it wasn't one...")
let wReason = args.join(" ").slice(27)
if (!wReason) return message.channel.send("Please tell me, why you want to warn this person. Because, you know, it's a warn :D");
if(!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send(oops)
if(wUser.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send(Mod)


if(!warns[message.guild.id]) warns[message.guild.id] = {
    user: wUser.id,
    warns: 0
}


warns[wUser.id].warns++



fs.writeFile("./warns.json", JSON.stringify(warns, null, 4), err => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
});

let warnEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Warned")
.setColor("YELLOW")
.addField("Warned User", `${wUser}`)
.addField("Moderator", `${message.author.id}`)
.addField("Reason", `${wReason}`)
.addField("Number of Warnings", warns[wUser.id].warns)
.addField("Warned at", `${message.createdAt}`)

let warnonEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Warned")
.setColor("YELLOW")
.addField("Warned on", `${message.guild.name}`)
.addField("Moderator", `${message.author}`)
.addField("Reason", `${wReason}`)
.addField("Warned at", `${message.createdAt}`)
        
let logchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === 'id');
if(!logchannel) return 

wUser.send(warnonEmbed)
logchannel.send(warnEmbed)

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular layout doesn't make a lot of hierarchical sense.  You might want to nest the user inside the guild and any parameters belonging to the user inside that.  Something like this...

```
"superniceguildid": 
{
    "636302212787601408":
    {
        "warns": 3
    },
    "7837439745387549":
    {
        "warns": 1
    }
},
```

Accessing it then would be as easy as using something like the following:

```js
let guildWarns = warns["superniceguildid"];
let userWarns = guildWarns["636302212787601408"];
let numberOfWarns = userWarns.warns;
```

you can combine that as well.

```js
let numberOfWarns = warns["superniceguildid"]["636302212787601408"].warns;
```

Of course, remember that if it doesn't exist it will be undefined.

Comment: Ok, and how can I generate that File? The current one I have cant genereate it like in your answer:
```
if(!warns[message.guild.id]) warns[message.guild.id] = {
    user: wUser.id,
    warns: 0
}```

Comment: You just move the user portion out as if you were accessing the object like I did in the last line... ``if(!warns[message.guild.id]) warns[message.guild.id][wUser.id] = { warns: 0 }`` or ``if(!warns[message.guild.id]) warns[message.guild.id][wUser.id].warns = 0``

Comment: Got the following Error: 
`if(!warns[message.guild.id]) warns[message.guild.id][wUser.id] = {
                                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '673322453476442122' of undefined`

Sorry if im annoying, but im realy new in this xD

Comment: @Mr Brickstar I had that backwards, but that is an indication you did not create the guild object first.  Try this ``if(!warns[message.guild.id) { warns[message.guild.id]= {}; }`` then use ``warns[message.guild.id][wUser.id] = { warns: 0 };``